# why interface is showing with blue border in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I am using Xcode 9.4, my layouts are showing as below image. Can anyone tell me solution ?

[image: See image]

Answer (score 4):

Goto your storyboard and uncheck below options:

1. Show Layout Rectangles
2. Show Bounds Rectangles

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default it showing lite blue in color, if use change the canvas it will results in dark blue in color. Go in menu -> Editor -> canvas and change as per your wish.